# File cannot be accessed because it is being used by another program

Tags: c#, file-io

I am trying to remove the space at the end of line and then that line will be written in another file.

But when the program reaches to `FileWriter` then it gives me the following error

> Process can't be accessed because it is being used by another process.

The Code is as below.

```
private void FrmCounter_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\abc", "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        string activeDir = @"D:\dest";
        System.IO.StreamWriter fw;
        string result;

        foreach (string file in filePaths)
        {
            result = Path.GetFileName(file);
            System.IO.StreamReader f = new StreamReader(file);
            string newFileName = result;
            // Combine the new file name with the path
            string newPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(activeDir, newFileName);
            File.Create(newPath);

            fw = new StreamWriter(newPath);

            int counter = 0;
            int spaceAtEnd = 0;
            string line;

            // Read the file and display it line by line.
            while ((line = f.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (line.EndsWith(" "))
                {
                    spaceAtEnd++;
                    line = line.Substring(0, line.Length - 1);
                }
                fw.WriteLine(line);
                fw.Flush(); 
                counter++;
            }

            MessageBox.Show("File Name : " + result);
            MessageBox.Show("Total Space at end : " + spaceAtEnd.ToString());
            f.Close();
            fw.Close();
        }
}
```

Comment: Well, the file is obviously opened by another program. Perhaps try to close it if it is opened as a window? Perhaps another program has it opened just like you are trying to?

Comment: At a guess, because you setting activeDir and filePaths to the same directory, you are trying to write to the same file you are reading from.

Comment: Well i tried another directory also.. but same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`File.Create` itself returns a stream.

Use that stream to write file. Reason you are receiving this error is because Stream returned by `File.Create` is open and you are trying to open that file again for write.

Either close the stream returned by `File.Create` or better use  that stream for file write or use

```
Stream newFile = File.Create(newPath);
fw = new StreamWriter(newFile);
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though you solved your initial problem, if you want to write everything into a new file in the original location, you can try to read all of the data into an array and close the original `StreamReader`.  Performance note: If your file is sufficiently large though, this option is not going to be the best for performance.

And you don't need `File.Create` as the `StreamWriter` will create a file if it doesn't exist, or overwrite it by default or if you specify the `append` parameter as `false`.

```
result = Path.GetFileName(file);
String[] f = File.ReadAllLines(file);  // major change here... 
                                       //  now f is an array containing all lines 
                                       //  instead of a stream reader

using(var fw = new StreamWriter(result, false))
{
    int counter = f.Length; // you aren't using counter anywhere, so I don't know if 
                            //  it is needed, but now you can just access the `Length`  
                            //  property of the array and get the length without a 
                            //  counter

    int spaceAtEnd = 0;

    // Read the file and display it line by line.
    foreach (var item in f)
    {
        var line = item;

        if (line.EndsWith(" "))
        {
            spaceAtEnd++;
            line = line.Substring(0, line.Length - 1);
        }
        fw.WriteLine(line);
        fw.Flush(); 
    }
}

MessageBox.Show("File Name : " + result);
MessageBox.Show("Total Space at end : " + spaceAtEnd.ToString());
```

Also, you will not remove multiple spaces from the end of the line using this method.  If you need to do that, consider replacing `line = line.Substring(0, line.Length - 1);` with `line = line.TrimEnd(' ');`

Answer (score 0):

You have to close any files you are reading before you attempt to write to them in your case.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

Zafar is correct, however, maybe this will clear things up.

Because File.Create returns a stream.. that stream has opened your destination file. This will make things clearer:

```
File.Create(newPath).Close();
```

Using the above line, makes it work, however, I would suggest re-writing that properly. This is just for illustrative purposes.

Comment: you are right Simon, but i edited the destination path, thought i am getting same error

Answer (score 0):

Write stream in **using statement** like:

```
using (System.IO.StreamReader f = new StreamReader(file))
{
   //your code goes here
}
```